# How can I recreate this concrete-looking grunge background in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, background, texture

See the background in this website. How do I achieve this effect ?

[image]

Comment: Hi Ashish, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. Could you tell us what you tried that didn't work? Always good to show some effort, and your chances for a good answer increase. If you have any questions, please see the [help center](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help) or ping one of us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: try your luck at [CGtextures](http://cgtextures.com/), a site dedicated to textures, free for download. Add some Photoshopping and stir vigorously :)

Comment: I'm certain I picked up [this link](http://www.demilked.com/free-grunge-textures-backgrounds/) from a Q&A here but can't find which.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try googling 'dark black grunge texture' then on Photoshop use selected texture and in the layers panel select Multiply or reduce the opacity slightly (10 -20%).
Remember to have a black background colour.

Comment: Though I figured it out myself, still thanks a lot for your help! I did the exact same thing. :)

Comment: Please comment if you find a solution! Other people may not know.

Comment: I like this texture library
http://www.mayang.com/textures/